# How to handle Errors on never ending chain with materialize?

Tags: swift, error-handling, uikit, rx-swift

Imagine the following chain where a user wants to save a list of some sort:

```
var saveChain = userTappedSaveListSubject
        .doOnNext { list -> Void in // create pdf version
            let pdfFactory = ArticleListPDFFactory()
            list.pdf = try pdfFactory.buildPDF(list)
            try database.save(list)
        }
        .flatMap { list in
              AuthorizedNetworking.shared.request(.createList(try ListRequestModel(list)))
                    .filter(statusCode: 201)
                    .map { _ in list }
        }
        .doOnNext { list in
            list.uploaded = true
            try database.save(list)
            try Printer().print(list)
    }
    .materialize()
    .share()
```

On every operator in the chain errors can occur, which would terminate the stream and the user would be unable to retry saving and printing the list (the whole chain gets disposed).

In the end the user should see either a "success" or "failure" screen by binding the observable to a textField:

```
Observable.of(
        saveChain.elements().map { _ in
            ("List saved!", subtitle: "Saving successfull")
        }, 
        saveChain.errors().map { error in
            ("Error!", subtitle: error.localizedDescription)
        })
        .merge()
```

**How should the error be handled?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the obvious fix:

```
let saveChain = userTappedSaveListSubject
    .flatMap { list in
        Observable.just(list)
            .do(onNext: { list -> Void in // create pdf version
                let pdfFactory = ArticleListPDFFactory()
                list.pdf = try pdfFactory.buildPDF(list)
                try database.save(list)
            })
            .flatMap { list in
                AuthorizedNetworking.shared.request(.createList(try ListRequestModel(list)))
                    .filter(statusCode: 201)
                    .map { _ in list }
            }
            .do(onNext: { list in
                list.uploaded = true
                try database.save(list)
                try Printer().print(list)
            })
            .materialize()
    }
    .share()
```

However, there are a host of problems with this code because of the mixed paradigms.

- You are passing around a mutable class inside your Observables. This is problematic because it's a functional paradigm so the system expects the contained type to be either a struct/enum or an immutable class.
- Your reliance on side effects to load up said mutable class object again is quite odd and against the paradigm.

Comment: Thank you. Can you point to some recommended ressources on functional programming paradigm? Or provide a solution to updating the model in a mvvm architecture with rx?

Comment: The "Rx Design Guidelines" might help you: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj4ubq65YnkAhUDJt8KHf1RATYQFjAAegQIABAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2F4%2FE%2F4%2F4E4999BA-BC07-4D85-8BB1-4516EC083A42%2FRx%2520Design%2520Guidelines.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3f0dzqP1MwIY4-LLe0hOhN